# How to set the monitor on button?

Tags: android, button

I add the button dynamic in android. How to set the monitor on button?

I want to realize a function like I add a button into the main interface, how to add a monitor on this button.

Then I accept a voice message. How to play the voice message?

Comment: you wanted a button listener? http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/

Answer (score 0):

```
myBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Start accepting voice message
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but it is not the same address. how to deal with the different corresponding address?

Comment: address? Please elaborate your question. I am not getting it